# (Wordpress) How to get custom taxonomy parent name?

Tags: categories

I'm using **custom taxonomies** and **custom post type** in my blog and everything is running fine so far.

The problem is, I've made a small query to list all my child categories, but now I can't get the name of each parent because of the condition on line 10.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$args = array(
        'orderby' => 'id',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'taxonomy' => 'album'
);             

$categories=get_categories($args);
foreach($categories as $category) {
if($category->parent!=0) {
?>
<li class="span3">
<div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="<? bloginfo('url'); ?>/album/<?php echo $category->category_nicename; ?>" rel="nofollow">
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/covers/<?php echo $category->category_nicename; ?>.jpg" alt="">
        </a>

        <div class="caption">
                <a href="<? bloginfo('url'); ?>/album/<? echo $category->category_nicename; ?>">
                        <? echo $category->parent . ' - ' . $category->name; ?>
                </a>
        </div>
</div>
</li>
    <?
    }
}
    ?>
```

Any workaround?

Comment: Please [edit] your questions to include your code here. A question should not depend on an external site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using two nested `foreach` you prevent n+1 db queries, where n is the number of child terms:

```
<?php
$_cats = array();
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'id', 'order' => 'ASC', 'taxonomy' => 'album'
);             
$categories = get_categories($args);
if ( ! empty($categories) ) { foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    if ( $category->parent != 0 ) {
        if ( ! isset($_cats[$category->parent]) ) {
            $_cats[$category->parent] = array( 'terms' => array() );
        }
        $_cats[$category->parent]['terms'][] = $category;
    } else {
        if ( ! isset($_cats[$category->term_id]) ) $_cats[$category->term_id] = array();
        $_cats[$category->term_id]['parent_name'] = $category->name;
        $_cats[$category->term_id]['terms'] = array();
    }
} }
if ( ! empty($_cats) ) { foreach( $_cats as $parentid => $children ) {
  if ( ! empty($children['terms']) ) { foreach( $children['terms'] as $term ) {
    $album_url = site_url() . '/album/' . $term->category_nicename;
    $cover =  site_url() . '/covers/' . $term->category_nicename . '.jpg';
?>
<li class="span3">
<div class="thumbnail">
  <a href="<?php echo $album_url; ?>" rel="nofollow">
    <img src="<?php echo $cover; ?>" alt="<?php echo $term->name; ?>">
  </a>
  <div class="caption">
  <a href="<?php echo $album_url; ?>">
    <?php echo $children['parent_name'] . ' - ' . $term->name; ?>
  </a>
  </div>
</div>
</li>
<?php } } } } ?>
```

... and please, the right PHP open tag is `<?php` not `<?`.

Comment: AFAIK there's nothing wrong with using `<?` instead of `<?php`, it's just shorthand. Can you expalin why people shouldn't use that? Thanks for this answer.

Comment: From official PHP docs (bold mine): "PHP also allows for short open tags `<?` and `?>` **which are discouraged** because they are only available if enabled with short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option." @Rev

Comment: Ah. So it's not that it's necessarily bad, it's just on some servers it might not work or could stop working. Makes sense, thanks.